# \includepdf[pages=-]{file.pdf} doesn't work

Tags: pdfpages

I have Tex Live installed. Everything look fine, pdfpages show any particular page I want, but when i want to print all pages via command:

```
 \includepdf[pages={1-5}]{vyzkum/Form.pdf}
  ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
  <to be read again> 
               -
  l.6014 \includepdf[pages={1-5}]{vyzkum/Form.pdf}
```

or

```
   \includepdf[pages=-]{vyzkum/Form.pdf}
   ! Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file `-'.

   See the pdfpages package documentation for explanation.
   Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
    ...                                              

   l.6014 \includepdf[pages=-]{vyzkum/Form.pdf}
```

The default (no range spacified):

```
  \includepdf{vyzkum/Form.pdf}
```

It shows only the first page

Any comment/help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: You haven't shown any usable example but I would guess you are using babel with a language that makes `=` or `,` active. try `\shorthandoff{=}`

Comment: There was just yesterday a similar question: you are probably using `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` or `\usepackage[slovak]{babel}`.

Comment: yep, it is duplicate (\usepackage[czech]{babel} was used). I didn't think it might be related to something else than pdfpages - therfore I couldn't find any useful answer - thanks!