# How can add page in pdf file after determine page in pdflatex

Tags: thesis

I write a dissertation in English, and I want to add a page from PDF file (in Arabic) after the title page in PDF latex, I used the formulas

```
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\includepdf[pages=-]{file.pdf}
```

but the page appeared empty, can anyone help me

Comment: First check the most common Question is your problem caused by using babel see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230808/includepdfpages-file-pdf-doesnt-work

Comment: Package pdfpages Warning: I will use a dummy \includepdf command
(pdfpages)                which will NOT insert any pages, because
(pdfpages)                you are producing DVI output.

Comment: A warning appears above

Comment: You need to include a simple [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) including your starting preamble down to \begin{document} \includepdf… \end{document} and explain what compiler command you use / selected to trigger a DVI route

Comment: I ask about compilation command because it sounds similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52190/pdfpages-includepdf-not-working